# @Parcelize in multi-platform project

Tags: android, kotlin, parcelable, kotlin-android-extensions, kotlin-multiplatform

I'd like to create a class in a multi-platform project, and use `Parcelize` to make it `Parcelable` in the Android version.

So in my `lib-common` project, I tried:

```
expect annotation class Parcelize()
expect interface Parcelable

@Parcelize
data class Foo(x: Int): Parcelable
```

and in my `lib-android` project:

```
actual typealias Parcelize = kotlinx.android.parcel.Parcelize
actual typealias Parcelable = android.os.Parcelable
```

The first problem was that the Gradle plugin `kotlin-android-extensions` didn't seem to take in `lib-android`'s `build.gradle`, so the package `kotlinx.android.parcel` was not found. I managed to work around that by just importing the library directly:

```
implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-android-extensions-runtime:$kotlin_version"
```

With this, the `actual` definition of `Parcelable` compiles.

However, I am getting an error from the definition of `Foo`, as if it was not properly annotated with `@Parcelize`:

> Class `Foo` is not abstract and does not implement abstract member `public abstract fun writeToParcel(p0: Parcel!, p1: Int): Unit` defined in `android.os.Parcelable`

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Well that's a bit embarrassing, but I've figured out the problem was simply because I forgot to turn on the experimental features of `kotlin-android-extensions`, one of which is `@Parcelize`...

So to get it work, it was enough to keep my `expected` and `actual` definitions of `Parcelable` and `Parcelize` as in the question, and edit `lib-android`'s `build.gradle` and add the following lines:

```
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'
androidExtensions {
    experimental = true
}
```

No `dependencies` additions are needed; that was a dead end direction.

Comment: Additional, I have needed to add the dependency : implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-android-extensions-runtime:$kotlin_version"

Comment: Your comment should be added to this answer @oguzhan ! I also needed this dependency !

Answer (score 6):

Since Google deprecated `android-kotlin-extensions` plugin, you should use `kotlin-parcelize` plugin

```
apply plugin: 'kotlin-parcelize'
```

[Source](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2020/11/the-future-of-kotlin-android-extensions.html)

Comment: Is kotlin-pacelize android-specific?